# Where do I find the fine tools for locks

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Some locks require "deft hands, fine tools", where do you find the fine tools ?

Is it a craftable items or do you need to buy them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's an Inquisition perk of the "Secrets" category](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisition_perks#Secrets).

In order to buy it, you'll need to have bought 4 other perks in the same category.

Comment: It is annoying that some objects require this skill, the grey warden quest contain an object that requires this skill !

Comment: Lots of the areas and missions have areas that require this skill, I've got locked buildings all over the place. I just unlocked this, so I'm now going back over old maps to find out what's inside those places. However having agents active in a category counts towards your total of 4 so that help, so you probably only need to increase your searching range and map scouting in order to get this anyway.